# Want jTextField to lose focus when I click on the main window

Tags: java, swing

I've been struggling with this for way too long.  When I'm done typing in a jTextField, I want it to lose focus when I click on the window outside the textfield.  I can't figure out how to do this.  The best I can to is transfer focus to the next textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to lose focus? I'm sure there is better design then to force the user to click on the window to cause the text field to lose focus.

Anyway, the text field will lose focus when another component gains focus. By default a panel is not focusable so clicking on it will not cause the text field to lose focus. Make the panel focusable:

```
panel.setFocusable( true );
```

Of course now when the user uses the tab key, the panel will now be included in the tab order. Thats another reason this seems like a bad design.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this in netbeans.  I have the focusable property checked, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I can try inserting the code after the panel is created.  I want to get the focus out of the textfield b/c after editing it, I want to be able to use my keyboard shortcut "p" to activate a button.  I suppose I can give the button focus when anything else loses focus.

Comment: Sorry, setFocusable() will only work when tabbing from component to component. If you are using the mouse then you need to add a MouseListener to the panel and then use the requestFocusInWindow() method to give focus to the panel. Now you begin to see why "Alt-P" is the standard approach to invoke a button on the frame. You don't force the user to take this extra step of having the text field lose focus. Companies like MS have spend lots of money to develop workable GUI's. Any time you go away from the normal design you will have a complicated UI that a user need to learn. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your class extends JFrame:

```
JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField();

addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTextField1.setFocusable(false);
            }
        });
```

Hope this help...